# z-index of iframe child does not work as desired

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, z-index

I have a website with an iframe and the website has its own backdrop / overlay. My goal is to set z-index of a child element of iframe, so only this child element should be on top of the overlay. I have access to both website inside iframe and the top website.

I reproduced it in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/57inkZB1xjI4zisKCwBJ), so my goal is to get the green box (modal) to the top.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html" width="100%" height="500px" ></iframe>
   <div class="backdrop">
       Backdrop
   </div>
  </body>
```

Do you have an idea if it's possible? How?

Comment: No, that is not possible. An iframe is an independent window instance, and z-index does not work across such.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want.

What you have is this:

```
document
   body
     iframe
       - see document(2)
     div[class="backdrop"]

document(2)
   body
     div[class="modal box"]
```

The two documents don't overlap and cannot interact with each other in such way. You can move your element to the top z-index **within** the iframe, but you cannot make the element "break out" of the iframe in the way you wish to achieve. You have to set the iframe itself to the top.

An alternative approach for you might be to use an ajax request, and then append the new element to the body, and style that to appear on top.